# What does overProvisioned Memory mean for Lambda in AWS Cloudwatch?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to learn more about monitoring and analysis of lamda functions in my serverless environment, to understand how to point out 'suspect' lambdas that need attention. I have running through some sample queries in Logs Insights sections, and I have a few lambdas that have this result.

[image]

I'm basically trying to understand if this is something that needs fixing quickly, or if it's not a big deal if there is so much overProvisioned memory?

Should I be more worried looking at Duration/Concurrency issues than this metric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **TLDR**: overprovisioned memory and duration affects billing cost. Both parameters can be controlled where possible to cost-effective values.

Allocated memory, together with duration and number of times the lambda is executed per month is used for computing billing cost for the month. <sup>[[1]](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/)</sup>

Currently, the lambda uses roughly 14% of provisioned memory at maximum load, the remaining fraction can be utilised.

If you're serving a huge amount of request, reducing over-provisioned memory and duration can be cost effective.

My recommendation is to provision memory to be `sum of max load plus (50% - 75%) of max load` and reviewing the duration.

Concurrency doesn't factor in monthly billing cost. 
Some numbers: <sup>[[2]](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/managing-aws-lambda-function-concurrency/)</sup>

- `Default concurrency limit for functions = 100`
- `Hard set concurrency limit for account = 1000`

Reducing the duration, means you can serve more requests at a time. 
The concurrency limit per account can be increased when requested to the AWS Support.

Another typical workaround for concurrency issues is to throttle requests using a queue. This may be more costly.

1. The lambda receiving the request creates a new SNS topic, envelopes it together with request, pushes it to a message queue and returns caller the topic.
2. Caller receives and subscribes to topic.
3. Another lambda processes the queue and report status for the job to the topic.
4. Caller receives message.

Account limit for number of topics is set at 100,000 <sup>[[3]](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/)</sup>.
This limit can be increased by requesting to AWS Support. Although cleaning up topics that are no longer necessary to keep around can be more suitable.

> Having to design through this workarounds for concurrency limits could mean that the application requirements are more suited for traditional web application backed by a long running server.